# Обобщение Parent<Child extends Parent<Child>>

Tags: java, generics, интерфейс

Допустим, требуется реализовать следующую абстракцию (приведённый код – псевдо-Java):

```
public abstract class ChatService {        
    public abstract class LocalBinder</*КлассПотомок*/ extends ChatService> {  
        public abstract /*КлассПотомок*/ getService();
    };
}
```

**Вопрос:** возможно ли реализовать это отношение в Java, и если да, то каким способом?

Все попытки решить эту проблему приводят меня к сомнительным решениям, в роде этого:

> Класс-родитель:

```
public abstract class ChatService<T extends ChatService<T>> extends Service {
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public T getService() {
            /*Допустимо ли это преобразование?*/
            return (T) T.this; // Warning: Unchecked cast from ChatService<T> to T
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: А для чего и как вся эта конструкция должна использоваться?

Comment: Я, если честно, не до конца понимаю вообще ситуацию. Разве можно оверрайдить внутренний класс? И в какой момент не получается подставить конкретную имплементацию вместо Т?

Comment: @Regent для того, чтобы написать обобщённую реализацию интерфейса `MyServiceConnection<T extends ChatService> implements ServiceConnection`, которая позволяла бы получить доступ к методам сервиса `T`.

Comment: А зачем LocalBinder обязательно внутренний должен быть?
 Такой вариант чем не подходит: http://pastebin.com/mN8iCEfT?

Comment: @iksuy возможно такой вариант мог бы и подойти, если бы `ChatService` не наследовал `Service`, а `LocalBinder` не наследовал `Binder`. Я это опустил сугубо для упрощения восприятия вопроса.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous а вы уверены, что вам действительно это всё нужно делать через внутренний класс? Возможно, из-за принятия такого решения вы и оказались в тупике. Применять `@Override` к классу, например, вообще некорректно. Как вы собираетесь пользоваться таким `LocalBinder`-ом, который можно создать, только предварительно создать экземпляр `ChatClientService` (что делает бессмысленным вызов `getSerice`, ибо сервис уже и так есть), тоже непонятно.

Comment: @Regent нет, я в этом не уверен: здесь я слепо повторяю решение https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html?hl=ru , в котором `LocalBinder` предлагается определить внутри `LocalService`.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous да, вижу. А в чём проблема с тем, что возвращается как `ChatService`? Судя по статье, binder создаётся локально и используется только в методе `IBinder onBind`. Это, на мой взгляд, корректное и допустимое использование локального класса. А вы хотите как-то по-другому использовать `LocalBinder`?

Comment: @Regent проблема в том, что через `ChatService` нельзя будет получить доступ к методам различных его потомков (если не сделать для них один общий интерфейс на уровне родителя). Конечная цель в данном случае просто уйти от повторяемости кода: https://github.com/DukeSpontaneous/Bluetooth-Chat/blob/master/BluetoothChat/src/by/spontaneous/bluetoothchat/MainActivity.java (от анонимных реализаций `ServiceConnection`).

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous предположим, что `ChatClientService.LocalBinder` начнёт возвращать `ChatClientService`, а не `ChatService`. Каким образом это поможет избавиться от дублирования кода в этом месте?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52784/discussion-between-dukespontaneous-and-regent).